# Using ASan on a single shared object

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

I have an executable that is linked against multiple shared objects. One of the shared objects is compiled with ASan and the executable itself isn't.
Is there a way to make ASan track this shared object only?
Is there an alternative to using LD_PRELOAD here?

Answer (score 2):

The only supported way in this case is to compile (and link) shared object with `-fsanitize=address` and set `export LD_PRELOAD=$(gcc -print-file-name=libasan.so)` when running the executable.